# CORS error in aws api gateway service, only one way work

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I get cors errors in api gateway service, The situation is very odd :

- If create a resource in console and enable cors option inside wizard, everything is ok!
  [image]
- If create a resource in console and enable cors by `enable cors` from Actions menu, got cors error :(

[image]

- If create a resource in console and create `OPTIONS` method manually, got cors error .
- If create a resource using aws cli, got cors error !

In three ways that i get cors error, everything is followed by documents and same as first way that work , but when i test it got cors error .

In aws documents these ways all ways must have same result,and i put * for allow origin header .
If is there any differences, then what is it ?

Comment: My problem solved by adding mapping template in option method in integration request section.

Answer (score 0):

One common catch for API Gateway and Lambdas is that if you use HTTP integration between the Lambda and API Gateway, you will be able to modify the headers, query strings, path parameters and body in both the request and response.

On the hand, if we use HTTP Proxy Integration, we can only modify the headers, query strings and path parameters in the request and not the response. I have a hunch that you will have to specify in your functions the response headers including the CORS headers.

```js
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({ isHandled: true }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type,x-api-key",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET,DELETE",
      },
    };
```

Comment: thanks , but my problem solved by adding mapping template in option method in integration request section.

Comment: Custom integration i see!